# How can I find vendor name from MAC address of my NIC

Tags: algorithm

So far I learned having my first **3 bytes** of my **MAC address**(HEX format: `00:00:00`:00:00:00) I can find my NIC's **vendor name**(which is a string). Can you elaborate this algorithm? No websites/tools links please

Comment: You do not find a string but an identifier (OUI). After you can match ID with the producer... Give it a look [MAC Address deails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Address_details) and to the [Organizationally unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizationally_unique_identifier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not find a string but an identifier (OUI, or Organizationally unique identifier), a code that you can match with a list. (In three bytes you couldn't push an arbitrary long string.)

[image]
<sup>Image from wikipedia</sup>

For further references you can give it a look to the wiki page of [MAC Address deails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Address_details) and to the one about the [Organizationally unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizationally_unique_identifier).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, it's just an assigned value by IEEE for the vendor/organization.
Reference: https://aruljohn.com/mac.pl

Comment: On Superuser, we always provice a short answer, and use links only as reference.